# neovim vscode replace word under cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

I am using neo vim extension in vscode.

I want to replace the word under cursor. Usually it is just a minor change to the existing word, so I have it available in the replace part. I have the below line in my init.vim

`nnoremap ^ :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/<C-r><C-w>/g`

When I invoke the binding with `^`, the appropriate command appears as shown in image below.
[image: vscode command window]
 However on pressing return no changes take effect. If I place the same command in the command window by pasting or typing and hit return, then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mapping didn't work for me either, but I've found a workaround:

```
nnoremap <leader>sr :<C-u>call VSCodeNotify('actions.find', { 'query': expand('<cword>')})<CR>
```

So `,sr`  opens the quick find window with the word under cursor. Then you have to push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> to get the replace field also.
Unfortunately the same with `editor.action.startFindReplaceAction` doesn't work.

The same works for `workbench.action.findInFiles` but not for `workbench.action.ReplaceInFiles`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "before": ["<Space>","s","r"],
    "after": ["*",":", "%","s","/","/"]
},
```

this works for me using regular vim in VSCode